# How to add each byte of an 8-byte long integer?

Tags: c, assembly, sse, mmx

I'm learning how to use the Intel MMX and SSE instructions in a video application.  I have an 8-byte word and I would like to add all 8 bytes and produce a single integer as result.  The straightforward method is a series of 7 shifts and adds, but that is slow.  What is the fastest way of doing this?  Is there an MMX or SSE instruction for this?

This is the slow way of doing it

```
unsigned long PackedWord = whatever....
int byte1 = 0xff & (PackedWord);
int byte2 = 0xff & (PackedWord >> 8);
int byte3 = 0xff & (PackedWord >> 16);
int byte4 = 0xff & (PackedWord >> 24);
int byte5 = 0xff & (PackedWord >> 32);
int byte6 = 0xff & (PackedWord >> 40);
int byte7 = 0xff & (PackedWord >> 48);
int byte8 = 0xff & (PackedWord >> 56);
int sum = byte1 + byte2 + byte3 + byte4 + byte5 + byte6 + byte7 + byte8;
```

Comment: please add your code and the aspired result

Comment: A single 8-byte integer?

Comment: `psadbw` where the other operand is zero.

Comment: Or ... the old "horizontal byte sum via multiplication" trick - wouldn't `((PackedWord * 0x0101010101010101ULL) >> 56)` work as well ?

Comment: psadbw where the other operand was zero worked.

Comment: @FrankH. actually I don't think it does, what if the second highest byte overflows? It works as the last step in a popcnt because then that overflow can never happen

Answer (score 5):

Based on the suggestion of @harold, you'd want something like:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

inline int bytesum(uint64_t pw)
{
  __m64 result = _mm_sad_pu8(*((__m64*) &pw), (__m64) 0LLU); // aka psadbw
  return _mm_cvtsi64_si32(result);
}
```

Comment: +1 Learn something new today.  Look like it would readily adapt to a _uint128_t.

Comment: It's usually better to use SSE2, not MMX, even if you only need one 64-bit horizontal sum, rather than two.  Then you don't need an EMMS before returning.  `__m128i result = _mm_sad_epu8(_mm_cvtsi64x_si128(pw), _mm_setzero_si128);` should compile to the same MOVQ / PXOR-zeroing / PSADBW / MOVD.  I forget which of the `64x` / `64` intrinsics is available for 32-bit code, but MOVQ (as a load from memory) definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a horizontal sum-by-multiply after one pairwise reduction:

```
uint16_t bytesum(uint64_t x) {
    uint64_t pair_bits = 0x0001000100010001LLU;
    uint64_t mask = pair_bits * 0xFF;

    uint64_t pair_sum = (x & mask) + ((x >> 8) & mask);
    return (pair_sum * pair_bits) >> (64 - 16);
}
```

This produces much leaner code than doing three pairwise reductions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an assembly guru but this code should be a little bit faster on platforms that don't have fancy SIMD instructions:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int bytesum(uint64_t pw) {
    uint64_t a, b, mask;

    mask = 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffLLU;
    a = (pw >> 8) & mask;
    b = pw & mask;
    pw = a + b;

    mask = 0x0000ffff0000ffffLLU;
    a = (pw >> 16) & mask;
    b = pw & mask;
    pw = a + b;

    return (pw >> 32) + (pw & 0xffffffffLLU);
}
```

The idea is that you first add every other byte, then every other word, and finally every other doubleworld.